# Remove time input from DateTimePicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Does anyone know how to remove (or at least hide) the time option from the bootstrap datetimepicker?

**As displayed on web page**

[image]

**As defined in the cshtml**
[image]

The data type in the DB is a DateTime, but providing a time is not necessary for the user. So ideally we'd like to hide it, or obfuscate it, whilst still using the same control. We can use javascript if absolutely necessary, but I feel there must be an attribute I can affix to the field in the model (or similar) that I'm missing!

Comment: Then why are you using a datetimepicker as opposed to a datepicker?

Comment: A datepicker requires javascript to initialise. Not inherently a problem, but I wanted to explore the non-js options first.

Comment: There is nothing you can do in the server. Your displaying a control generated by a jquery plugin - its that code which displays the 'time' selector at the bottom left in your image

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this script

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {              
           $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                 format: 'MM/dd/YYYY'
           });
        });      
    </script>
```

Also try to add this to your Html.EditorFor

```C#
 "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}"
```